# Springboot3 on AWS Lambda: getAwsProxy in Lambda stream handler throws ClassCastException

Tags: spring-boot, aws-lambda, spring-boot-3

I am trying to run a springboot3 application on AWS lambda. My application runs fine locally. I am using gradle/kotlin to build a fatjar, uploading that to s3, and invoking it as a lambda function. My handler looks like this:

```
public class LambdaStreamHandler implements RequestStreamHandler {
    private static SpringBootLambdaContainerHandler<AwsProxyRequest, AwsProxyResponse> handler;
    static {
        try {
            System.out.println("initializing LambdaStreamHandler");
            handler = SpringBootLambdaContainerHandler.getAwsProxyHandler(Application.class);
            System.out.println("set hander");
        } catch (ContainerInitializationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new RuntimeException("Could not initialize Spring Boot application", e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void handleRequest(InputStream inputStream, OutputStream outputStream, Context context)
            throws IOException {
        System.out.println("Inside of handleRequest...");
        handler.proxyStream(inputStream, outputStream, context);
    }
}
```

I'm seeing this in cloudwatch:

```
initializing LambdaStreamHandler
...

Error loading class com.my.application.aws.LambdaStreamHandler: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext cannot be cast to class org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext (org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext and org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext are in unnamed module of loader com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.api.client.CustomerClassLoader @6193b845)
    at com.amazonaws.serverless.proxy.spring.SpringBootLambdaContainerHandler.initialize(SpringBootLambdaContainerHandler.java:191)
    at com.amazonaws.serverless.proxy.InitializationWrapper.start(InitializationWrapper.java:35)
    at com.amazonaws.serverless.proxy.spring.SpringBootProxyHandlerBuilder.buildAndInitialize(SpringBootProxyHandlerBuilder.java:79)
    at com.amazonaws.serverless.proxy.spring.SpringBootLambdaContainerHandler.getAwsProxyHandler(SpringBootLambdaContainerHandler.java:87)
    at com.my.application.aws.LambdaStreamHandler.<clinit>(LambdaStreamHandler.java:18)
    ... 2 more
```

Has anybody seen this before/know what the problem is or how I can resolve? I am considering changing from the java proxy to the lambda-web-adapter-runner approach

I've used this function as the proxy between spring and lambda, and was expecting that would work, but it seems to be expecting a different type of context.

Answer (score 0):

i had same issue, playing with spring-boot code i found the exact class that caused me troubles (not sure why yet) and i replace it with a prev working logic which end up working. i still wonder why the original setup doesnt work well for me tho.

here is the class after my adjustments

```
/*
 * Copyright 2012-2023 the original author or authors.
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *      https://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */

package org.springframework.boot;

import java.util.function.Supplier;

import org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils;
import org.springframework.boot.web.reactive.context.AnnotationConfigReactiveWebServerApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.core.env.ConfigurableEnvironment;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;

/**
 * Strategy interface for creating the {@link ConfigurableApplicationContext} used by a
 * {@link SpringApplication}. Created contexts should be returned in their default form,
 * with the {@code SpringApplication} responsible for configuring and refreshing the
 * context.
 *
 * @author Andy Wilkinson
 * @author Phillip Webb
 * @since 2.4.0
 */
@FunctionalInterface
public interface ApplicationContextFactory {

    /**
     * A default {@link ApplicationContextFactory} implementation that will create an
     * appropriate context for the {@link WebApplicationType}.
     */
   
  //marking out the DEFAULT behaviour and replacing it with logic from 2.5.12 which works for me
    //ApplicationContextFactory DEFAULT = new DefaultApplicationContextFactory();
    ApplicationContextFactory DEFAULT = (webApplicationType) -> {
        try {
            switch (webApplicationType) {
                case SERVLET:
                    return new AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext();
                case REACTIVE:
                    return new AnnotationConfigReactiveWebServerApplicationContext();
                default:
                    return new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Unable create a default ApplicationContext instance, "
                    + "you may need a custom ApplicationContextFactory", ex);
        }
    };

    /**
     * Return the {@link Environment} type expected to be set on the
     * {@link #create(WebApplicationType) created} application context. The result of this
     * method can be used to convert an existing environment instance to the correct type.
     * @param webApplicationType the web application type
     * @return the expected application context type or {@code null} to use the default
     * @since 2.6.14
     */
    default Class<? extends ConfigurableEnvironment> getEnvironmentType(WebApplicationType webApplicationType) {
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Create a new {@link Environment} to be set on the
     * {@link #create(WebApplicationType) created} application context. The result of this
     * method must match the type returned by
     * {@link #getEnvironmentType(WebApplicationType)}.
     * @param webApplicationType the web application type
     * @return an environment instance or {@code null} to use the default
     * @since 2.6.14
     */
    default ConfigurableEnvironment createEnvironment(WebApplicationType webApplicationType) {
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Creates the {@link ConfigurableApplicationContext application context} for a
     * {@link SpringApplication}, respecting the given {@code webApplicationType}.
     * @param webApplicationType the web application type
     * @return the newly created application context
     */
    ConfigurableApplicationContext create(WebApplicationType webApplicationType);

    /**
     * Creates an {@code ApplicationContextFactory} that will create contexts by
     * instantiating the given {@code contextClass} through its primary constructor.
     * @param contextClass the context class
     * @return the factory that will instantiate the context class
     * @see BeanUtils#instantiateClass(Class)
     */
    static ApplicationContextFactory ofContextClass(Class<? extends ConfigurableApplicationContext> contextClass) {
        return of(() -> BeanUtils.instantiateClass(contextClass));
    }

    /**
     * Creates an {@code ApplicationContextFactory} that will create contexts by calling
     * the given {@link Supplier}.
     * @param supplier the context supplier, for example
     * {@code AnnotationConfigApplicationContext::new}
     * @return the factory that will instantiate the context class
     */
    static ApplicationContextFactory of(Supplier<ConfigurableApplicationContext> supplier) {
        return (webApplicationType) -> supplier.get();
    }

}
```